# How to SUM up columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum

I would like to group by one column and sum up another column by doing so.

If I ask

```
SELECT * FROM Name_Data WHERE Name = 'Tim'
```

I will get a column named 'Count' that shows me how much Tim's there are per ZIPcode

```
ZIPcode Place           Year    Name    Count
3042    Kleinpolder     1993    Tim     7   
3042    Kleinpolder     2003    Tim     6   
3051    Kleiwegkwart    1983    Tim     14  
3051    Kleiwegkwart    1993    Tim     9   
3059    Nesselande      1993    Tim     8       
3059    Nesselande      2003    Tim     10  
3068    Ommoord/z       1983    Tim     24  
3068    Ommoord/z       2003    Tim     15  
3065    s-Gravenland    1993    Tim     21  
3011    Weena           2003    Tim     5
```

I would like to use GROUP BY ZIPcode and by doing so also sum up all the Count numbers. I have read how to use the SUM command but I can't figure out how to sum up the Count column.

So
3042 should be 7 + 6 = 13 
, 3051 should be 14 + 9 = 23 and so on..

Comment: In your output result set, which columns do you want to see? A simple `SUM()` aggregate would include just the grouped `ZIPCode` and the total `Count`. Including other columns (like year) may increase the complexity depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(`Count`) as `Count`,Name,ZIPcode 
from 
Name_Data 
WHERE Name = 'Tim'
group by ZIPcode
```